# Floating number upto two decimal PHP

Tags: php, floating-point

I know the question is very basic but it seems nothing working for me.

I have a number (either or float or integer) which I want to be formatted upto two decimal point. For this purpose I'm using PHP function `number_format` but it converts my number to string.

To convert it back to float I am using `(float)` or `floatval()`. But these functions just truncates the number after converting it to float from string.

**Here is my code**

```
$revenue_sum = array_sum(array_column($val2, 'weighted_revenue'));  //23722


$test = number_format($revenue_sum, 2);            //"23,722.00"
$test = (float)number_format($revenue_sum, 2);     //23.0
$test = floatval(number_format($revenue_sum, 2));  //23.0
```

I want the $test to be 23722.00 for the $revenue_sum = 23722

If $revenue_sum = 2372.2 the $test should be 2372.20

Comment: Once a number is a float, the extra decimal places have no purpose, they are only significant when you display the value - which is what `number_format()` is doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

number_format() function can be used as follows:

```
echo number_format($revenue_sum, 2,'.',''); // will return 23722.00 for the $revenue_sum = 23722
```

You are trying to type cast with ',' value, it is truncating the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

> `<?php echo sprintf("%2.2f", 8900.258); ?>`

which will output as

> `8900.26`

Comment: replace `echo sprintf` by `printf`

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a floating point value to a variable, then it is converted to an internal binary format (usually using IEEE 754). Not all possible values has an internal representation. So while scanning a text, the float is rounded to the nearest possible value. So for example `1.23` is rounded to `1.22999999999999998`.

Because of the internal representation, there is no difference between `100` or `1e2` or `100.0` or `100.0000`.

And when printing a floating point value without any formatting instruction, PHP guess a good format and rounding some digits. So `1.22999999999999` is displayed as `1.23`(may varies on different systems).

In general: As long you are calculating, formatting doesn't matter. It is mostly the best, to ignore the decimal fragments on debugging. But when printing (=converting to text), use functions like `format_number()` or any of the `printf()` functions.

To be more pragmatic: